# How to open line app with specified line user id chat screen?

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I am opening LINE app from my native iOS app and my requirement is, i need to open line app with specified user chat screen.

I am not able to open specified user chat screen with line URL scheme. I tried below URL schemes but it only open line app. Please help me on this where i am doing wrong.

```
line://oaMessage/UserlineID
https://line.me/R/ti/p/UserlineID
line://ti/p/UserlineID
```

Comment: please check this document https://developers.line.me/en/docs/messaging-api/using-line-url-scheme/

Comment: @a.masri I already review that but didn't find as i want. Can you please be more specific as i mention some example above.

Comment: Ok ,Please try this steps 1- open safari on your phone 2- open this url in safari `line://ti/p/{LINE_id}` , See what will happen Will he open the chat or not and tell me, Please make sure that the user ID is correct

Comment: @a.masri I tried this with 3 different line users but for everyone it says "User not found". Any idea ?

Comment: this deeplink open bot account `line://ti/p/UserlineID` do users their type bot account

Comment: @a.masri From where i can do this ? If it is possible to do this from line app then please provide me steps. Or anything else i need to do ?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya have you found any solution?

Comment: @Maulikpatel please check answer and let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. I finally found a solution:

```
http://line.me/ti/p/~{LINE_id}
```

Just add ~ in front of {LINE ID}

Answer (score 0):

With this way you can open line app with specified user.

```
if let url = URL(string: "line://ti/p/@UserlineID") {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Put your line id after @. Like line://ti/p/@jld859s8

Comment: It's not working anymore. I need to open a particular user chat screen either by phone number or line id.

Comment: @Maulikpatel As per my implementation it is working. I have one static line user and i am able to open it.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

```
if let url = URL(string: "line://ti/p/@UserlineID") {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url, options: [:],completionHandler:nil)
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be enhanced by adding some explanation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

For Line Messenger you can follow three general strategies to connect with other users:

Firstly, some others have already suggested this, you can use this link:

```
line://ti/p/<LINE_ID>
```

The problem is that this link has been depreciated due to a security vulnerability
source: https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/using-line-url-scheme/#if-the-user-hasn-t-installed-line

Secondly you can use the more recent link:

```
https://line.me/ti/p/<LINE_ID>
```

This redirects to a page with a Line Messenger QR Code, that your user can use to trigger the opening of the app. Its a halfway solution (although safer than #1)

Lastly if you want to save your users from the extra action/click, Line also allows you to download the QR Code from the app itself, so you could display that directly to your users in the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

They have updated their [documentation](https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/using-line-url-scheme/#sending-text-messages).

What we shall do now is follow this pattern

```
https://line.me/R/oaMessage/{LINE ID}/?{text_message}
```

For instance, if we want to send "Hello" to Line ID @abc, we shall use https://line.me/R/oaMessage/@abc/?Hello

I hope this helps someone who is searching for the latest available approach.

Answer (score 0):

line://ti/p/~phuongledao?oat_referrer=PROFILE

use this link to open the app from the browser

Answer (score -1):

> https://line.me/R/ti/p/UserlineID
>   line://ti/p/UserlineID

The above schemes don't always work (it could work with some UserID but not with others), I called Line support and they give me another alias for the UserID (this time without the @) and it works normally.